# Position half image on top of a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create this.
[image]

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble putting the image on top of the div like this.
How can I achieve this (CSS or JS)?

My current HTML:

```
<div className="account-container">
    <img src="" alt="Avatar" id="userAvatar"/>
    <div className="accountStats">
        ...Other Stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

My current CSS:

```
#userAvatar{
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 312px;
    width: 312px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
.accountStats {
    width: 760px;
    height:980px;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    box-shadow: 9px 9px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 18px;
}
.account-container {
    top: 30%;
    transform:translate(0, 30%);
}
```

Comment: Negative `margin-top`?

Comment: (Offtopic) Why you have sizes hardcoded in strict, instead of responsive units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a minus value for the `margin-bottom` so that the image drops to the bottom. Set the `margin-bottom` value to half of the image's height (in this case 156px) so that only half of the image lies above the `div`. Check this out:

```css
#userAvatar{
    margin-bottom:-156px; /* 156px is half of #userAvatar's height */
    margin-left:calc(380px - 156px); /* half of .accountStats's width - half of #userAvatar's height */
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 312px;
    width: 312px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
.accountStats {
    text-align:center; /* additional */
    padding-top:156px; /* half of #userAvatar's height */
    width: 760px;
    height:980px;
    background: #E0E0E0;
    box-shadow: 9px 9px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 18px;
}
.account-container {
    top: 30%;
    transform:translate(0, 30%);
}
```

```html
<div className="account-container">
    <img src="https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/7/618/png-transparent-man-illustration-avatar-icon-fashion-men-avatar-face-fashion-girl-heroes-thumbnail.png" alt="Avatar" id="userAvatar"/>
    <div class="accountStats">
        Other Stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add a suficient explanation. Code only answers are considered low quality as they are hard to udnerstand and therefor to reproduce.

Comment: Hi, it seems the margin-left was no needed, but every thing else works great. ♥

Answer (score 1):

Please test this:
margin-top: -156px;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually calculating left margin to set image in center, we can use flexbox.

```
.user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #efefef;
}

.account-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.card {
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px #ccc;
  background: white;
}

.user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
 #userAvatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -50px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.accountStats {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="account-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="user">
      <img id="userAvatar" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4587979/pexels-photo-4587979.jpeg" width="100px" height="100px" />
    </div>
    <div class="accountStats"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -4):

use the "position" atrribute

```css
#useravatar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    }
```